# Expand just one container tree node in navigator

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am using a navigator that has several container nodes at the top level with child nodes in each one. I wanted to have the navigator initially open with all the container nodes closed but one.

Using getComponent("navigator1").getTreeNodes()[0].setExpanded(true) does not seem to do anything (but I can use setLabel to change the label)... Anyone solve this issue before?

Howard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add property `expanded="false"` to all containers you want initially closed.

Example:

```xml
<xe:navigator
    id="navigator1"
    expandable="true">
    <xe:this.treeNodes>
        <xe:basicContainerNode
            label="Container 1"
            expanded="false">
            <xe:this.children>
                <xe:basicLeafNode label="Node 1.1"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                <xe:basicLeafNode label="Node 1.2"></xe:basicLeafNode>
            </xe:this.children>
        </xe:basicContainerNode>
        <xe:basicContainerNode 
            label="Container 2">
            <xe:this.children>
                <xe:basicLeafNode label="Node 2.1"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                <xe:basicLeafNode label="Node 2.2"></xe:basicLeafNode>
            </xe:this.children>
        </xe:basicContainerNode>
    </xe:this.treeNodes>
</xe:navigator>
```

Only Container 2 is initially expanded.

Comment: Thanks, I think the expandlevel I also had was preventing this from working. Appreciate the help!  Howard